# How can I capture html elements from .ts files?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying the learn Angular. They say typescript is a superset of javascript, but I can't manage to do things like getting elements from html, and modify it in the .ts file.

I'm trying to excecute a simple `document.getElementById` but I don`t know if how to acomplish it in typescript...

I have a componentn, and in the html, I placed a `<p>` element and assigned an `id` atribute to it. then from the typescript I'm trying to set a innerHTM to it but I haven't been able. Can anyone please tell me how is this achieved in typescript?

I tried the below code but doesn't work

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

const myContainer = document.getElementById('test') as HTMLInputElement;
myContainer.value = 'Hello from about';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',      
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because you have put your element manipulation code at the module level, which means it will be executed when the module is first required/imported, well before the component has actually been created and added to the DOM.

If you moved the get element / innerHTML lines into the ngOnInit function body, the element would exist.

However, this is not a good pattern to follow in an angular application. Instead you should be using property binding to set the value.

For example, in your template you could have `<p>{{message}}</p>` and on your component a property `message = "Hello from about"`

You can refer to the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions